# Extend Nginx on Elastic Beanstack - NodeJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Looking for a way to **extend** the nginx configuration on an elastic beanstalk environment. I just need a simple proxy like below so the single page app can hit the API via AJAX. We are not able to use CORS for our use case.

I followed the docs on Amazon but I am unable to get it to work. My current setup has the following folder structure:

node_app
.. .ebextensions
.... nginx
...... conf.d
........ 01_app_proxy.conf

```
location /api/v1 {
    proxy_pass          https://my-api.com;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Instance - Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason why it does not work is because the following settings

```
 .ebextensions .... nginx ...... conf.d ........ 01_app_proxy.conf
```

is for **Amazon Linux 1**. However, you stated that you are using **Amazon Linux 2**.

For AL2, the settings are in `.platform` folder, not in `.ebextensions` as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Also note, that there are **many differences between AL1 and AL2**. You may need to change other things if you are porting your app from AL1 to AL2 environment:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Marcin - you were dead right. I also had to change where I put the conf file also. To extend it, it had to go inside elasticbeanstalk folder .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_app_proxy.conf.